# Where to place Mouse Enter and Mouse Leave in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, mouseevent

I have the following script and am trying to add mouse enter and leave events on a slideshow such that when the mouse is over the image it won't switch to the next one, and once removed it continues.

I can get the slide to stop when the mouse is over but once the mouse is out the slideshow won't proceed.

I am unsure if these 2 lines are in the right place:

```js
   ---> jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseenter(function(){MOUSE_IN = true;});
   ---> jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseleave(function(){MOUSE_IN = false;});
```

```js
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('a').focus(function () {
    this.blur();
});
SI.Files.stylizeAll();
slider.init();

});

---> var MOUSE_IN = false;

var slider = {
num: -1,
cur: 0,
cr: [],
al: null,
at: 10 * 1000,  /* change 1000 to control speed*/
ar: true,
anim:'slide',
fade_speed:600,
init: function () {
    if (!slider.data || !slider.data.length) return false;

    var d = slider.data;
    slider.num = d.length;
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < slider.num; i++) {
        if(slider.anim == 'fade')
        {
          jQuery('#' + d[i].id).hide();
        }
        else{
            jQuery('#' + d[i].id).css({
                left: ((i - pos) * 1000)
            });
        }
        jQuery('#slide-nav').append('<a id="slide-link-' + i + '" href="#" onclick="slider.slide(' + i + ');return false;" onfocus="this.blur();">' + (i + 1) + '</a>');
    }
    jQuery('img,div#slide-controls', jQuery('div#slide-holder')).fadeIn();
   ---> jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseenter(function(){MOUSE_IN = true;});
   ---> jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseleave(function(){MOUSE_IN = false;});
    slider.text(d[pos]);
    slider.on(pos);
    if(slider.anim == 'fade')
    {
      slider.cur = -1;
      slider.slide(0);
    }
    else{
    slider.cur = pos;
    window.setTimeout('slider.auto();', slider.at);
    }
},
auto: function () {
    if (!slider.ar) return false;
    if(MOUSE_IN) return false;
    var next = slider.cur + 1;
    if (next >= slider.num) next = 0;
    slider.slide(next);
},
slide: function (pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= slider.num || pos == slider.cur) return;

    window.clearTimeout(slider.al);
    slider.al = window.setTimeout('slider.auto();', slider.at);

    var d = slider.data;
    if(slider.anim == 'fade')
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < slider.num; i++) {
         if(i == slider.cur || i == pos) continue;
         jQuery('#' + d[i].id).hide();
      }

      if(slider.cur != -1){
        jQuery('#' + d[slider.cur].id).stop(false,true); 
        jQuery('#' + d[slider.cur].id).fadeOut(slider.fade_speed); 
        jQuery('#' + d[pos].id).fadeIn(slider.fade_speed); 

      }
      else
      {
        jQuery('#' + d[pos].id).fadeIn(slider.fade_speed);
      }
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < slider.num; i++)
        jQuery('#' + d[i].id).stop().animate({
            left: ((i - pos) * 1000)
        },
        1000, 'swing');
    }
    slider.on(pos);
    slider.text(d[pos]);
    slider.cur = pos;
},
on: function (pos) {
    jQuery('#slide-nav a').removeClass('on');
    jQuery('#slide-nav a#slide-link-' + pos).addClass('on');
},
text: function (di) {
    slider.cr['a'] = di.client;
    slider.cr['b'] = di.desc;
    slider.ticker('#slide-client span', di.client, 0, 'a');
    slider.ticker('#slide-desc', di.desc, 0, 'b');
},
ticker: function (el, text, pos, unique) {
    if (slider.cr[unique] != text) return false;

    ctext = text.substring(0, pos) + (pos % 2 ? '-' : '_');
    jQuery(el).html(ctext);

    if (pos == text.length) jQuery(el).html(text);
    else window.setTimeout('slider.ticker("' + el + '","' + text + '",' + (pos + 1) + ',"' + unique + '");', 30);
}
};

if (!window.SI) {
var SI = {};
};
SI.Files = {
htmlClass: 'SI-FILES-STYLIZED',
fileClass: 'file',
wrapClass: 'cabinet',

fini: false,
able: false,
init: function () {
    this.fini = true;

    var ie = 0
    if (window.opera || (ie && ie < 5.5) || !document.getElementsByTagName) {
        return;
    }
    this.able = true;

    var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
    html.className += (html.className != '' ? ' ' : '') + this.htmlClass;
},
stylize: function (elem) {
    if (!this.fini) {
        this.init();
    };
    if (!this.able) {
        return;
    };

    elem.parentNode.file = elem;
    elem.parentNode.onmousemove = function (e) {
        if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;
        if (typeof e.pageY == 'undefined' && typeof e.clientX == 'number' && document.documentElement) {
            e.pageX = e.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            e.pageY = e.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        };
        var ox = oy = 0;
        var elem = this;
        if (elem.offsetParent) {
            ox = elem.offsetLeft;
            oy = elem.offsetTop;
            while (elem = elem.offsetParent) {
                ox += elem.offsetLeft;
                oy += elem.offsetTop;
            };
        };
        var x = e.pageX - ox;
        var y = e.pageY - oy;
        var w = this.file.offsetWidth;
        var h = this.file.offsetHeight;
        this.file.style.top = y - (h / 2) + 'px';
        this.file.style.left = x - (w - 30) + 'px';
    };
},
stylizeById: function (id) {
    this.stylize(document.getElementById(id));
},
stylizeAll: function () {
    if (!this.fini) {
        this.init();
    };
    if (!this.able) {
        return;
    };

    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var input = inputs[i];
        if (input.type == 'file' && input.className.indexOf(this.fileClass) != -1 && input.parentNode.className.indexOf(this.wrapClass) != -1) this.stylize(input);
    };
}
};

(function (jQuery) {
jQuery.fn.pngFix = function (settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
        blankgif: 'blank.gif'
    },
    settings);
    var ie55 = (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && parseInt(navigator.appVersion) == 4 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 5.5') != -1);
    var ie6 = (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && parseInt(navigator.appVersion) == 4 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 6.0') != -1);

    if (jQuery.browser.msie && (ie55 || ie6)) {

        jQuery(this).each(function () {
            var bgIMG = jQuery(this).css('background-image');
            if (bgIMG.indexOf(".png") != -1) {
                var iebg = bgIMG.split('url("')[1].split('")')[0];
                jQuery(this).css('background-image', 'none');
                jQuery(this).get(0).runtimeStyle.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='" + iebg + "',sizingMethod='" + settings.sizingMethod + "')";
            }
        });

    }
    return jQuery;
};
})(jQuery);
jQuery(function () {
if (jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 7) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of both lines is fine, they just add an event handler to the mouse in/out event. The problem you experience is actually in tha auto function, if you note, at the end of the init function you have:

```
window.setTimeout('slider.auto();', slider.at)
```

This line makes a call to the auto function after a slider.at time (which is 10 seconds in your example), the auto function checks if MOUSE_IN is set to true, if it's not, then calls the slide function, then in the slide function you have another call to the auto function:

```
slider.al = window.setTimeout('slider.auto();', slider.at);
```

But once you set the MOUSE_IN variable to true the auto function simply returns and it stop the execution of further slide functions, to solve this, you may want to either handle the MOUSE_IN logic in the slide function, or before returning false in the auto function, call with a time out the auto function again.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply and sorry for the late one.

I am still trying to wrap my head around this, as it is my first time using javascript.

what i am getting from your response if, If I were to use the same logic in any function if will still result in the same output?

Because once the auto function returns false the 2nd time, the slide function will not be called? Also if I were to call with a timeout the auto function again wouldnt that create an infinite loop :S

Comment: Silly question but is it possible to debug javascript? It would make my understanding of this soooo much better.

Comment: When the if statement returns false, it is similar to other languages where once it returns false it skips out of the function without doing the rest?

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks for the help, just one question. Are while loops safe? :P See my edited post ^

Comment: While loops are safe as long as you provide a valid exit clause and you don't clog your clients CPU. By the way to debug JavaScript you can use the Developer Tools of your browser, hitting F12 bring them in most of them.

Comment: Thanks, been using the chrome java console :)! It doesnt look like my while loop helped, it simply caused my page to freeze. For some reason the mouseleave event does not fire.

I have been reading a lot about the  .on and delegation or something. ANy idea if this would help?

Answer (score 0):

Thought this would work but it doesnt, the mouseleave eventdoesnt seem to fire.

```
jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseenter(function(){MOUSE_IN = true;});
jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseleave(function(){MOUSE_IN = false;});
while(MOUSE_IN==true)
{
jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseenter(function(){MOUSE_IN = true;});
jQuery('#slider-holder').mouseleave(function(){MOUSE_IN = false;});
}
```